# White space on top of the page in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm getting a big whitespace on top of my page after login only in firefox. I tried to inspect all elements and can't find anything wrong with it. I also checked for uncollapsing margin but can't find any.when I scroll down and then up space will be removed from the top but when I refresh the page space will come.

Here is my website link :-

http://wheels.futuratechgroup.com/

Answer (score 0):

There something wrong in your meta tag **VIEWPORT**
chage **width** which you are giving as **device-width**
may be it will help you